# Opening two Rstudio sessions while one is sinking

Tags: r, rstudio

In Rstudio I have one script which is running and using `sink()` to save the outputs to a text file. However, when I open up a second R studio session, while the first session is still running, it seems like I am unable to print anything to the console. How do you print to the console in Rstudio while another session is using `sink`?

For example open up Rstudio and start by setting workspace to source file, with this as your source file

```
#set up sinking
  logFile = file("logMod.txt")
  sink(file=logFile)
  N=10000;
  N.c=10000;
#run program
  for (i in 1:N){       
    for (j in 1:N.c){
        if( i*j %% 10000==0 ) print(i*j)
    }
  }
sink()
```

then open up another Rstudio session and try to print to console. I can't do it. I can open the standard R gui and print to console but not Rstudio. This is all done on a windows machine.

Comment: What do you mean by "open a second R studio session"? If you mean starting another rstudio process I can't replicate the behavior you describe.

Comment: @Ista Yes this is what I think I mean. See edited question.

Comment: Windows/Linux/Mac? Sounds like a platform problem and likely an RStudio problem, I'd badger their support platforms.

Comment: I've never had that problem and I'm usually using 3-5 Rstudio projects at the same time.